# Match a field in a column if another row has an entry

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So basically, if the "applied" column has a "yes" entry for a corresponding company, I want that same entry to be relayed if the same company comes up again as to not have to re-input the data. How would I do this?

[image: Screenshot of worksheet]

Answer (score 0):

No VBA Here.
If what you're looking for is how to tell if **the combination of all three columns** is duplicated... For example, you are only checking if someone **named bob**, who **is an accountant**, **at google** is a duplicate, then here is how.

> formula in cell F2 in my example
> =IF(COUNTA(FILTER($C$2:$C$17,($A$2:$A$17&$B$2:$B$17&$C$2:$C$17)=A2&B2&C2))>1,"DUPLICATE","-")

[image: Formula at work]

[image: Plain Example]

You can use this to identify which lines to add a yes to or which line to delete depending on your expected outcome.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that if a company was already marked as "yes" under the "applied" column the "yes" is applied once again, automatically, if an entry with the same company is inputted in another field/row

Comment: You can definitely do that, but you'll need to either: **A)** use the modified version of my above formula: `=IF(COUNTA(FILTER($C$2:$C$17,($A$2:$A$17&$B$2:$B$17&$C$2:$C$17)=A2&B2&C2))>1,"Yes","")` and replace all empty cells in your "Applied" column with that formula. Then you can just replace the cell contents with a "Yes" every time you want to manually mark something yes. Excel might get peeved at you for inconsistent formulas, and you might run into issues down the line with the fragility of formulas vs cell value. or...

Comment: **Bi)** (best for if you're manually entering this data) You could write a macro to automatically do that check... but it's going to have to watch for a selection change or calculation trigger. or **Bii)** (best for if you import this data in chunks from some other source) have a button trigger to pull all the data into an array, look for unmarked duplicate lines and replace "" with "Yes".   <>   Every option has its pros and cons.